# Linux find and remove

Tags: linux

Hello the below is not removing the files that are ending with char 'o' but I'm not sure why.

```
find . -name '.*o' -type f -ok rm '{}'
```

here is my current error

[image: error]

Thanks so much!!

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text into the reddit message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
find . -name '*o'  -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

While Jatinj Mehrotra is correct, there are still two things unmentioned:

1. `-exec` and `-ok` are simmilar, but not the same. `-exec` will execute your command on every file `find` finds. `-ok` will actually ask you for every single file or directory, if you are `ok` with executing the command on it.
2. Your actual problem is, that you are missing a `\` befor your `;`. In shell the semi-colon is a delimiter for a command. So `command1; command2` will be interpreted as if you typed `command1`, then pressed enter, and then  typed `command2` and press enter. But in this case the semicolon is actually a parameter to `find -exec`. It tells `find` that you want that command executed on every single item individually. You can also use a `+`, which tells find to replace the `{}` with a space-seperated list of everything it finds.